# Проблема с выводом string после её обработки C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clion

Вообще изначально требуется помощь в написании программы на C++ которая шифрует RU Алфавит, знаки препинания и цифры методом Цезаря ( перестановкой на 1-2 символа ). Я написал две программы разными методами и очень хотелось бы получить коментарии касательно кода и что я сделал неправильно? Проблема заключается в том, что в обоих случаях выводятся непонятные символы после отработки программы. Пример показан в скриншоте ниже. Пишу тут впервые, так что прошу прощения за возможные нарушения в порядке и оформлении :)Данная проблема появляется в обоих случаях. Что я делал? Я понял что скорее всего эта проблема заключается в кодировке, я использовал UTF-8, не особо силён в этом. В общем прошу знающих людей мне помочь как в написании программы, так и в разъяснениях почему у меня возникла данная ситуация. Код приложу ниже. Во втором случае я писал программу с встроенным алфавитом string. Там так же. Проверял в Clion и Visual Code. Как на Windows так и на Linux.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int index = 0;
string input;

cout << "Введите данные для шифровки" << endl;
getline(cin, input);


const int number = input.size();
char cipher[number - 1];


for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    int symbol = input[index];
    symbol += 1;
    cipher[index] = symbol;
    index += 1;
}

cout << cipher << "\n";


int amount = strlen(cipher);
char decipher[amount];
index = 0;

for (int a = 0; a < amount; a++)
{
    int mark = cipher[index];
    mark -= 1;
    decipher[index] = mark;

    cout << decipher[index];
    index += 1;
}

return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы забыли о том, что строки в C/C++ должны завершаться нулем. Поэтому правильно будет -- `char cipher[number + 1];`, а после первого цикла (шифрования) надо добавить `cipher[index] = 0;` (ну и в самом конце для красоты печати я бы добавил `cout << '\n';`)

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за ответ, очень выручили. Если знаете, не подскажете ещё один момент? (Скрин прикладываю ниже). Шифрует EU алфавит и цифры в рамках существующего и понятного нам людям алфавита, но если стоит пустить на вход программе RU алфавит, то при шифровании программа показывает новые символы, так и должно быть? Это правильная отработка программы? Мне непонятно почему программа не шифрует в рамках RU алфавита, как это происходит с цифрами и EU алфавитом, а затрагивает какие то непонятные символы. Это особенности кодировки? В данном случае UTF-8? https://imgur.com/a/a0xUECv

Comment: UTF-8 это кодировка с переменной длиной кода.  Все ascii кодируются одним байтом (вы видите при шифровании след. символ), а русские буквы 2-мя байтами. Вы прибавляете 1 к каждому из байтов этой пары, вот код и получается уже из совсем другого (например, армянского) алфавита (или может стать вообще не представимым в кодировке utf-8). Можете почитать о utf-8, например, в вике, а также поищите таблицы кодирования unicode (utf-8 это одна из разновидностей кодирования unicode) в google и внимательно посмотрите на них

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за столь развернутые ответы!